# best way to persist date as string

Tags: java, web-services, ejb-3.0, tapestry

How to best persist Date property as string property of ejb3 entity?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author nikola
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHART")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Chart.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Chart c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Chart.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Chart c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Chart.findByAmount", query = "SELECT c FROM Chart c WHERE c.amount = :amount"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Chart.findByAmountdue", query = "SELECT c FROM Chart c WHERE c.amountdue = :amountdue")
})
public class Chart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;
    @Column(name = "AMOUNTDUE")
    private Double amountdue;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private String dateofbirthString;
    @javax.persistence.Transient
    private Date dateofbirth;

    public Chart() {
    }

    public Chart(Double amount, Double amountdue) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.amountdue = amountdue;
        this.dateofbirth = new Date();
    }

    public Chart(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Double getAmountdue() {
        return amountdue;
    }

    public void setAmountdue(Double amountdue) {
        this.amountdue = amountdue;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Chart)) {
            return false;
        }
        Chart other = (Chart) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Chart[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Date getDateofbirth() {
        return dateofbirth;
    }

    public void setDateofbirth(Date dateofbirth) {
        this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void convertDateToString() {
        dateofbirthString = String.valueOf(dateofbirth);
    }
}
```

Entity needs to be sortable by date in tapestry application and ejb session needs to use date for some calculations too?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it depends on how much information about the dates you plan to store. Usually you use a `Date` field with an `@Temporal` annotation, defining it as either `TemporalType.DATE`, `TemporalType.TIME` or `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`. You should go for `TIMESTAMP` if you're in for some ordering, changing this:

```
@Column(name = "date")
private String dateofbirthString;
```

Into this:

```
@Column(name = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateofbirth;
```

Remember to change the accessors accordingly. Another tip: you can map a `Calendar` directly instead of a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose either timestamp (even though it is ackwarard to keep it long as String) or choose one of the DateFormat predefine formats for easy and straightforward conversion between String and Date types.